# Shrinkwrap constraint has no effect on some objects

Tags: constraints, shrinkwrap

I struggle to shrinkwrap objects to the surface of a mesh. It works well with the default cube.

But it doesn't work with objects in a collection although I have the same settings. These objects were imported with blender-gis from a .shp file and extruded based on a field value. The objects are separated.

Here you see it works well for the default cube:
[image: The default cube]

But not for an object from the collection. It is still hovering in the air:
[image: The object from collection]

Comment: Try this: Object → Set Origin → Origin to Geometry.

Comment: Damn, that worked! Thanks! Little detail I did not pay any attention to.

Comment: It's because you have hided object centers. This is useful information in some cases.